# Calculate position on the border of rotated rectangle if position on border of origin rectangle is known

Tags: geometry

Asking for advise for a little specific task.

> I have a point outside of the rectangle. Point is projected to the rectangle's border at right angles. The rectangle may be rotated around it's center to any angle (also point can moving around rectangle).

For a simple example a took $3$ variations of rectangle's $\alpha = 0°$ **(red)**, $\alpha = 45°$ **(blue)** and $\alpha = 18°$ **(green)**. Also height $h$, width $w$ and $X$, $Y$ (*center of the rectangle*) are given.

I can calculate $X_1 Y_1$ with simple math. But calculating $X_2 Y_2$ or $X_3 Y_3$ is a more difficult task. So how can I calculate $X_2 Y_2$ and $X_3 Y_3$?

Picture for demo:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUKSD.png)

Comment: What if there is no perpendicular from the point to the rectangle border?

Comment: You can calculate how much the distance is increased based on the rotation.

Comment: @Moti Then is an exceptional case. I think it'll be a corner.

Comment: Would you like to show us how you calculated the values $X_1$ and $Y_1$? Our aim is to customize our answer to suit you, because there are several ways to do his.

Answer (score 1):

Finding which side of the rectangle $p$ is nearest to isn't difficult. After this you want to find the closest point on that side to $p$. We'll call its coordinates $P_1,P_2$. You should be able to find the slope of the nearest side to $p$ and write its direction vector $\langle a,b \rangle$. You'll then want to solve $\langle a,b \rangle \cdot \langle x-P_1,y-P_2 \rangle=0$ for $x,y$, where $x,y$ give the coordinates of a point on the side; this will let you find a point where the line from $p$ to the side is perpendicular to the side. If the side is not vertical, this gives you a system of two equations to solve:
$$a(x-P_1)+b(y-P_2)=0\\a(y-c)-bx=0$$
where $c$ is the $y$-intercept of the line parallel to and going through the nearest side to $p$. $x,y$ is the point you want.

After seeing your comment, I still don't see an easy way to solve this problem using trig in the way I assume you desire. The corners add to the difficulty of finding a general solution from finding the new nearest point to $p$ after a rotation by $\alpha$ given the old nearest point. You will probably want to use the tangent function to calculate the slope given $\alpha$, though.

$a(y-c)-bx=0\implies y=\frac{b}{a}x+c$ which you may be more familiar with, this is to ensure the point you find is on the nearest side of the rectangle. The first equation will be more difficult to explain further if you are not familiar with the dot product, essentially we are trying to find two perpendicular slopes. If $p$ is not on a line $\ell$, the line going through $p$ that is perpendicular to $\ell$ will give the nearest point on $\ell$ to $p$ at the intersection.

Here is an explanation based solely on intuition, so no knowledge of linear algebra or calculus is required: let a circle $C$ slowly expand out of $p$, its center. Eventually, $C$ will touch some point of $\ell$, and upon this happening, let $C$ stop growing. Since $p$ is the same distance $r$ from all points on $C$ and no part of $\ell$ is inside $C$, the intersection of $C$ and $\ell$ must be the nearest point. $\ell$ is the tangent line of the circle at this intersection; a line drawn between $p$ and the point where the tangent line intersects the circle is perpendicular to this tangent line and thus $\ell$. Note there is only one line through $p$ that is perpendicular to $\ell$. Thus our goal is to find a line perpendicular to $\ell$ that goes through $p$, for then we know the intersection of these two lines is the nearest point on $\ell$ to $p$.

None of this works for corners but finding a corner position when one is the nearest point on the rectangle is easy.

Comment: I thought the problem can be solved with trigonometry. Any thoughts?

Comment: Or can you explain your answer more deeper? It will be nice if with some more details and concreteness.

Comment: You calculate the line through (x,y) that represents the tilting of the square. You find the distance from this line (Euclidian geometry - Pythagorean theorem, trigonometry). Subtract half the side.